# Why logical "and" predicates do not work?

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog, datascript

Tested on [datascript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript) 1.3.0

datoms:

```clj
[{:db/id -1 :name "Smith" :firstname "Oliver" :age 20}
 {:db/id -2 :name "Jones" :firstname "Oliver" :age 20}
 {:db/id -3 :name "Smith" :firstname "Amelia" :age 16}
 {:db/id -4 :name "Jones" :firstname "Amelia" :age 16}]
```

tried to query with logical `and` predicates below who are named Smith and aged older than 18 years, why did it return the unfiltered whole set?

```clj
'[:find ?firstname ?name
  :where
  [?p :name ?name]
  [?p :firstname ?firstname]
  [?p :age ?age]
  [(and (= ?name "Smith") (> ?age 18))]]

;;; wrong result: #{[Oliver Smith] [Oliver Jones] [Amelia Smith] [Amelia Jones]}
```

then changed to query with discrete predicates and got the satisfied result as expected.

```clj
'[:find ?firstname ?name
  :where
  [?p :name ?name]
  [?p :firstname ?firstname]
  [?p :age ?age]
  [(= ?name "Smith")]
  [(> ?age 18)]]

;;; correct result: #{[Oliver Smith]}
```

Do `datomic` and `datascript` or `datalog` in general only support data patterns scattered to discrete clauses? Are conventional logical operations `and` etc. incompatible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query/query.html) you cannot use an `and-clause` just like that. The only way you can use an `and-clause` is when it is inside an `or-clause`:

> Inside the **or** clause, you may use an **and** clause to specify
> conjunction. This clause is not available outside of an or clause,
> since conjunction is the default in other clauses.

Comment: link to [Or Clauses](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query/query.html#or-clauses).

Answer (score 3):

This is because AND is implicit. All clauses are implicitly joined by AND as in they all must be true at the same time for the query to match